How do you authenticate against Azure Artifacts during running of azure pipelines?
We have a private azure repo with some of our artifacts in it:
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/bridgette/letspretend/_packaging/thisistherealaddress/npm/registry/
I have my pipeline, mostly unaltered from the default one for publishing a nodejs webapp
# Node.js Express Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js Express app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
  - main

variables:
  - group: azure-artifacts
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  - name: azureSubscription
    value: "waap-waap-waap-waaaaaaa"

  # Web app name
  - name: webAppName
    value: "MYAPP-Dev"

  # Environment name
  - name: environmentName
    value: "MYAPP-Dev"

  # Agent VM image name
  - name: vmImageName
    value: "windows-latest"

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "20.x"
            displayName: "Install Node.js"

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "Install vsts-npm-auth"
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                try {
                  echo "Install vsts-npm-auth"
                  npm install -g vsts-npm-auth
                  echo "vsts-npm-auth Installed"
                }
                catch {
                  echo "vsts-npm-auth failed to install"
                  exit 1
                }

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "Running vsts-npm-config"
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                try {
                  Write-Host "Running vsts-npm-config"
                  vsts-npm-auth -C .npmrc -F -N
                }
                catch {
                  Write-Host "Debug: Outputting .npmrc"
                  Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\.npmrc
                  exit 1
                }

            continueOnError: false
            condition: succeeded()
            env:
              NPM_AUTH_TOKEN: $(NPM_AUTH_TOKEN)

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "npm install"
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                npm install
            continueOnError: false
            condition: succeeded()

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "Outputting npm logs on failure."
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                Write-Host "Debug: Outputting npm log contents due to npm install failure"
                Get-ChildItem -Path "/home/vsts/.npm/_logs/" -File | ForEach-Object {
                    Write-Host "==============================================="
                    Write-Host "Contents of $($_.FullName):"
                    Write-Host "==============================================="
                    Get-Content $_.FullName
                    Write-Host ""
                }
            continueOnError: false
            condition: failed()

          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: "npm build"
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                npm run build --if-present
            continueOnError: false
            condition: succeeded()

          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            displayName: "Archive files"
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveType: zip
              archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              replaceExistingArchive: true
            condition: succeeded()

          - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            artifact: drop
            condition: succeeded()

  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy stage
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        environment: $(environmentName)
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureWebApp@1
                  displayName: "Azure Web App Deploy: MYAPP-Dev"
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
                    appType: webAppLinux
                    appName: $(webAppName)
                    runtimeStack: "NODE|10.10"
                    package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
                    startUpCommand: "npm run start"

I have tried a plethora of things.
My first attempt (when it was an ubuntu-latest pool image) was to alter the .npmrc file in the local directory of the project with:
@evo-uikit:registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/bridgette/letspretend/_packaging/thisistherealaddress/npm/registry
//pkgs.dev.azure.com/bridgette/letspretend/_packaging/thisistherealaddress/npm/registry:_authToken={$NPM_AUTH_TOKEN}
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
always-auth=false

And setting npm auth token as an environment variable, either as my own PAT, or as a base64 of System.AccessToken (which I think is incorrect, because base64 of that is weeeeeird! I have never seen spaces in a BASE64 string, so not sure if System.AccessToken is an array, maybe???)
Neither of these worked, I continued to get the error:
npm error code E401
npm error Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.

Catting out the logs, I was seeing the following:
751 verbose stack HttpErrorAuthUnknown: Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/***, Basic realm="https://pkgsprodeau1.pkgs.visualstudio.com/", TFS-Federated
751 verbose stack     at /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/20.16.0/x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:80:17
751 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
752 verbose statusCode 401
753 verbose pkgid @blah-blah/text/@https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/bridgette/letspretend/_packaging/thisistherealaddress/npm/registry/@blah-blah/text/-/text-0.1.2.tgz
754 error code E401
755 error Unable to authenticate, your authentication token seems to be invalid.

After much searching of stack overflow, I determined that we had to use vsts-npm-auth, so I migrated the pipeline to windows-latest, as vsts-npm-auth is not cross plat.
Tried with both the PAT token in the .npmrc file, and without, and now I am seeing:
vsts-npm-auth v0.43.0.0 
-----------------------
Creating npmrc file. Path: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.npmrc
Getting new credentials for source:https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/bridgette/letspretend/_packaging/thisistherealaddress/npm/registry/, scope:vso.packaging_write vso.drop_write
Couldn't get an authentication token for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/bridgette/letspretend/_packaging/thisistherealaddress/npm/registry/.
Couldn't get an authentication token for https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/bridgette/letspretend/_packaging/thisistherealaddress/npm/registry/.

I ran vsts-npm-auth -C .npmrc -F -N as without the -N, it is waiting for you to open a browser and authenticate via a code, which, if this is a CICD pipeline, this is not ideal. I want to be be able to configure it so that my azure hosted pipeline can publish to and pull from my azure hosted artifacts to my azure hosted environment... I really shouldn't need a human in the midst of this pipeline loading a browser to say "yep, this azure pipeline in my azure environment is definitely trustworthy!"
I have in other pipelines used the following:
      - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
        displayName: "NuGet Authenticate"
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.SHOULD_PUBLISH, 'true'))

which has allowed me to do NPM tasks like publishing:
      - task: Npm@1
        inputs:
          command: "publish"
          publishRegistry: "useFeed"
          publishFeed: "blah/blahblah"
        displayName: "npm publish"
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.SHOULD_PUBLISH, 'true'))

And I presume there is an equivalent install command, but we have other pipelines that do not use NPM for installing or publishing packages (we also have a rushjs monorepo that uses rush install and rush publish, so this needs to be resolved inside a bash or powershell script.
Hoping that someone out here knows how to resolve that 401 error so that I can authenticate my pipeline to be able to publish to and read from our azure artifacts via NPM.

Does this help? Connect your npm project to Azure Artifacts.

Hi @BridgetteRyan, Good day to you. May I know if the suggestion to add the npmAuthenticate@0 task works for you? Thank you for your time and sharing.

You may try and add the npmAuthenticate@0 pipeline task in front of your bash script to run npm publish. This task will add credentials of the pipeline service account into the .npmrc file for subsequent npm publish command to authenticate against.
This also avoids hard coding the credentials in the .npmrc file of your repo.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: npmAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    workingFile: '$(packageDir)/.npmrc'
- bash: |
    npm install
    npm publish
  workingDirectory: $(packageDir)

.npmrc
registry=https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<MyOrg>/<MyProject>/_packaging/ProjectScopeFeed-npm/npm/registry/ 
                        
always-auth=true



Hi @BridgetteRyan, Good day to you. May I know if the suggestion to add the npmAuthenticate@0 task works for you? Thank you for your time and sharing.

Hi @AlvinZhao, sadly it did not.
We have moved away from using azure artifacts in general, as they have been nothing but a nightmare. When we migrated to npmjs.org, our scripts worked perfectly, with only changes to the authentication tokens.

That's for your time to share the update and your option to use nmjs.org feed. Cheers.
